# Do you need to call CoInitialize() when using Direct3D9?

Tags: com, direct3d9, ogre

My understanding was since D3D is using COM, the answer is yes. But in the Ogre rendering engine, it appears this is never called. Is this fine or an oversight - if so could it have some actual consequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not.  You don't use CoCreateInstance(), the interface types are not declared in IDL, you have to link to a .lib